# sqlite schema, need help understanding

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database before I dive into java programming to migrate the database. I understand SQLite is the way to go, and I have done days of research, but I'm stuck on creating the "Schema" or layout of my SQLite database. I'm at the point to where I'd just rather hire someone, even though this is just a hobby.

I want to create an app that involves phone/plans. First you pick your carrier, the plan, the phone and then the upgrade type to populate an estimate of the monthly bill. (My company already has the app created, I just want to form one free-hand to gain the knowledge for programming without viewing their code). I did research primary keys and such, I just don't know where to put everything.

Needed Table/Columns:

- Carrier
- Data Plans
- Device Access Fees
- Phone Model
- Phone Price
- Phone installment ( Per Month )

There's a few more that is needed, but honestly I just need help with the start. I've viewed many schemas online and examples from various websites. But I have no idea why I can't wrap my brain around the database layout. I've picked up java pretty quickly and understand the majority of the concepts; however, for some reason databases have so far killed my desire to continue.

Comment: don't overthink, just wade in and create your first table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sqlite3` command line utility (included in Sdk) to create and experiment with your DB before proceeding to do it an android application. This will save you lots of time.

For example, create your DB schema in a file, let's assume `mydb.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE carrier (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

# ...
```

then

```
$ sqlite3 --init mydb.sql mydb
```

and you can issue commands at the `sqlite>` prompt.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM carrier;
```

Once you are done, you can use the same schema for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:----
String sqltable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE
                + "(" + COLUMN_Carrier + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Data_Plans + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Device_Access_Fees + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Phone_Model + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Phone_Price + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Phone_installment  + " TEXT);";

```
    db.execSQL(sqltable);
```

where db is SQLiteDatabase object.